# Странное поведение select

Tags: javascript, angular2

Есть два `select`'а, второй зависит от первого:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Тип ТС:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control " type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.TransportTypeId">
                    <option *ngFor='let type of transportTypes' [ngValue]='type.Id' [textContent]='type.Name'></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Подтип ТС:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control " type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.TransportSubTypeId" (ngModelChange)="show()">
                    <option [ngValue]="undefined">Не указано</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let subType of transportSubTypes | filterBy: ['TransportTypeId']: item.TransportTypeId" [ngValue]='subType.Id' [textContent]='subType.Name'></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Подразумевается, что второй `select` может быть пустым (`undefined`). В начальный момент времени все работает отлично, в обоих `select`'ах есть значения, при изменении второго `ngModelChange` срабатывает. Но стоит мне выбрать какое либо значение в первом `select`'е, при котором фильтр для второго `select`'а возвращает пустой массив, то визуально второй `select` сбрсывается на значение `Не выбрано`, но при этом `ngModel` не становиться равным `undefined`,  атак и продолжает оставаться в том значении, в котором его застало это самое изменение первого `select`'а.

Как пример:

```
item.TransportTypeId = 1;
item.TransportSubTypeId = 1;
```

меняем:

```
item.TransportTypeId = 2;
```

Фильтр `filterBy` возвращает `[]`, `item.TransportSubType === 1`, но при этом выбрано значение `Не указано` и событие `ngModelChange` не происходит.

Помогите разобраться, как сделать так, что бы `select` автоматически сбрасывал значение модели.

**UPDATE**

Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что браузер не генерирует событие `change`, если выбирается "первое попавшееся значение", после удаления ранее выбранного элемента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел [оптимальное решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46600750/8142057):

> Решение: настраиваемая директива, которая будет прослушивать
>   изменения списка `<option>` и выбирать первый элемент, если ни один не
>   выбран.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mySelectFirstOption]'
})
export class SelectFirstOptionDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private observer: MutationObserver;

  constructor(
      private elementRef: ElementRef,
      private renderer: Renderer2) {
    if ((elementRef.nativeElement.tagName || '').toLowerCase() !== 'select') {
      throw new Error('mySelectFirstOption directive can only be applied to <select> elements');
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.trySelectFirstOption(), 0);
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => this.trySelectFirstOption());
    const config: MutationObserverInit = { childList: true };
    this.observer.observe(this.elementRef.nativeElement, config);
  }

  private trySelectFirstOption() {
    const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    if (nativeElement.options.length > 0 && nativeElement.selectedIndex === -1) {
      this.renderer.setProperty(nativeElement, 'value', nativeElement.options[0].value);
      nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
  }
}
```

И затем можно использовать его с помощью элемента `<select>`.

Comment: избегайте ссылок в ответе даже если они на stackoverflow.com, со временем ссылка может оказаться недействительной по той или иной причине. **P.S.:** если перенесенный ответ не совсем подходит для Вашего ответа, измените его пожалуйста для полного соответствия, т.к. возможно именно Ваше решение поможет другим нуждающимся в помощи участникам.

Comment: Ответ решает мою проблему, потому я его и опубликовал. Данная директива, после обновления списка выбирает нужный мне элемент (по умолчанию) и генерирует событие ``change``. Так же её можно слегка кастомизировать и настроить на выбор не первого попавшегося элемента, а нужного, согласно переданному значению.

Comment: абсолютно не против того, что Вы опубликовали ответ. представьте, что страница по ссылке по какой-то причине будет удалена, тогда любой кто столкнется с подобной проблемой будет видеть ответ **решение  - это настраиваемая директива...** без какого-либо пояснения в виде кода примера. Согласитесь, это будет не очень хорошо если Вы можете привести пример. Именно поэтому если Вы находите решение на ином ресурсе, то его вместе с кодом(при наличии такого) лучше опубликовать в **своем** ответе, а ссылку лишь привести в качестве источника.

Comment: По вопросу ссылки я Вас понял :) Учту :)